# How to plot the graph of double integral in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, integral

I'm new to Matlab and would greatly appreciate if anyone could help.
I have double integral which i calculated using quad2d() function:

```
>> syms x y
>> ymin=@(x)x.^2    
>> ymax=@(x)2*x
>> fun=@(x,y)x+y
>> quad2d(fun,0,2,ymin,ymax)

ans =  3.4667
```

How can i plot the graph of the integral?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well your integral is definite and the outcome is a number. What exactly do you expect to be plotted?

Comment: i want to plot the integral for different values of x

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `quad2d`, why not define `fun` as a symbolic function, perform [symbolic integration](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html) and then use [`ezplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ezplot.html) to plot the result?

Something along these lines:

```
syms x y t
fun = x + y;
I = int(fun, 0, t, x ^ 2, 2 * x);
ezplot(I)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot the integral for different values of x limits (in the above example it is between 0 and 2) you can do something like this:

```
counter = 1; 
for xmin = 0:10
    xminv(counter) = xmin;
    xmax = xmin+2;
    xmaxv(counter) = xmax;
    z(counter) = quad2d(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax);
    counter = counter +1;
end

plot(xminv,z);
```

Of course you can change the range that you do the integral instead of 2 to any value you want. For example if you want your `x` changes from over a range of 3 instead of 2 change the `xmax` from `xmax=xmin+2` to `xmax=xmin+3`.

Comment: thank you! but this gave me an empty graph. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, use plot(xminv, z) instead.